# Angular updateTag function doesn't update meta tag in source view HTML

Tags: angular, meta-tags, angular-services

In my application, I need to update meta tag after some API requests subscriptions are done. At `ngInit` method I added some tags -

```
addMetaTags(config){
        this.title.setTitle(config.title);

        this.meta.addTag({ property: 'og:type', content: config.type });
        this.meta.addTag({ property: 'og:site_name', content: 'AB' });
    }
```

it works fine, I can see the meta in source HTML.

But when my subscriptions are done, I updated meta by at first removing tags and then updating tag.

```
removeMetaTags(){
        let description: HTMLMetaElement = this.meta.getTag('name = "description"');
        this.meta.removeTagElement(description);

        let ogType: HTMLMetaElement = this.meta.getTag('name = "og:type"');
        this.meta.removeTagElement(ogType);
        let ogSite: HTMLMetaElement = this.meta.getTag('name = "og:site_name"');
        this.meta.removeTagElement(ogSite);
        let ogTitle: HTMLMetaElement = this.meta.getTag('name = "og:title"');
        this.meta.removeTagElement(ogTitle);
    }

updateMetaTags(config){
        this.title.setTitle(config.title);

        this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: config.description });

        this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:type', content: config.type });
        this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:site_name', content: 'ABCD' });
        this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:title', content: config.title });

        let description: HTMLMetaElement = this.meta.getTag('name = "description"');
        console.log(description);
    }
```

In console, I see the `description` meta tag element but when see source HTML it is not there.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you the DOM not updating and suggest to use `ChangeDetectorRef`

```
updateTag: Observable<any>;
_data;
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
```

Invoke the via service

```
  this.example.subscribe(data => {
        this._data = data;
        this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:title', content: config.title });
    });
```